# Is there a command to physically identify a particular Allied Telesyn switch in a rack among multiple switches?

Tags: command-line-interface, switch, rack

I have several identical older Allied Telesyn switches (model AT-FS8326) mounted in a rack without any labeling. I know their IP addresses and I have the access to their CLI over the SSH protocol. I would need to physically identify the switch's position in a rack to which I'm connected to over the SSH, so that I can replace it with new switch without disturbing the rest of the network.

Is there such command in the AT CLI that when issued would light some indicator on the switch's front panel to identify that particular switch?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that although I have the access to the switch via telnet protocol, I cannot actually use the CLI directly, because the switch presents a menu driven user interface and I'm limited only to options offered through the menu. Therefore, even if a command like "findme" existed in the CLI language, I wouldn't be able to issue it directly.

In that sense, the only usable solution to this problem is indeed the soft reload, which is available through the device's menu.

Answer (score 0):

Soft RESTART could be helpful.

Comment: It is actually the "reload" command in the CLI version for AT-FS8300 series of switches, but I was looking for something that doesn't disturb the network. In the newest CLI versions for AT-GS900 series of switches there is the "findme" command that does just what I need - flashes the LED indicators on the front panel for a specified amount of time.

Comment: You wanna to replace that switch, your network will be disturbed anyway - that "reload" command should satisfy. Have You checked the AT-FS8300 documentation, maybe?

Comment: My problem is that I don't want to replace the wrong switch, as I have to retain as much of the original configuration as possible, including it's IP address. If I don't identify the switch precisely, I may cause a lot more disturbance then necessary. Yes, I have checked the CLI reference, but it's hundreds and hundreds of pages, and I'm not even sure what to look for, as the equivalent command may have a different name or may not even exist. I'm only sure that there is no "findme" which exists in the newest version of CLI.

Comment: I know that reload would have to suffice if there is no alternative, but I'd like to confirm that there's definitely not one.

Comment: How many of those switches are there. You could setup a "dummy" VLAN(or some other setting) on one of his ports, plug your laptop in it and see how it behaves...Also, if you can see how many and which ports are active on him, that info shoul help You to define/locate him

Comment: @G.100sic Can't find any trace of those models(AT-FS8300) on the internet. Can You provide me a link?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, it's been a busy week. Regarding the switch model name I made an honest mistake, it's actually AT-8326GB, a member of the 8300 series of switches (there's also a AT-8350GB, 48-port model) which share the common CLI. It's rather old family of switches, they were acquired around 2004. Here are some links:
https://www.alliedtelesis.com/sites/default/files/documents/datasheets/8326gb_ds.pdf
https://www.cnet.com/products/allied-telesis-at-8326gb-switch-24-ports-managed-desktop-series/